# Find $k\in\mathbb{R}$ given $w = k+i$ and $z=-4+5ki$ and $\arg(w+z)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, plane-geometry

I am working on problem 2B-11 from the book Core Pure Mathematics, Edexcel 1/AS. The question is:

The complex numbers $w$ and $z$ are given by $w = k + i$ and $z = -4 + 5ki$ where $k$ is a real constant. Given at $\arg(w + z) = \frac{2\pi}{3}$, find the exact value of $k$.

I have attempted this question, but by answer is different from the given one and I can't figure out why. My answer:

Let $w + z = a + bi$.

$a = k - 4 \\
b = 1 + 5k$

The angle of the triangle formed by the vector $w + z$ (on Argand diagram) and the x-axis is $\pi -\frac{2\pi}{3} = \frac{\pi}{3}$

$\tan\frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{b}{a} \\
\tan\frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{1 + 5k}{k - 4} \\
k\tan\frac{\pi}{3} - 4\tan\frac{\pi}{3} = 1 + 5k \\
k\tan\frac{\pi}{3} - 5k = 1 + 4\tan\frac{\pi}{3} \\
k = \frac{1 + 4\tan\frac{\pi}{3}}{\tan\frac{\pi}{3} - 5} = -2.42$

However, the given answer is:

$\frac{4\sqrt{3} - 1}{5 + \sqrt{3}} = 0.88$  where $\tan\frac{\pi}{3} = \sqrt{3}$

I have just noticed that assuming the angle is $-\tan\frac{\pi}{3}$, my answer is correct. How can you tell the quadrant of $w + z$ when the constant $k$ appears in both $a$ and $b$?

Comment: There is no reason to say that the angle is \pi - \frac {\pi}{3}.  You should just stick with $\frac {2\pi}{3}$, and say $\tan \frac {2\pi}{3} = \frac {b}{a} = -\sqrt 3$  Second, never replace the exact value of an irrational number with a decimal approximation in math class.  Fine to do it in physics, but not math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $k\in\Bbb R,\,w:=k+i,\,z:=-4+i5k$ and $\arg(w+z)=\frac{2\pi}{3}$

Of course $w+z=(k-4)+i(5k+1)$. Since $0\lt\frac{2\pi}{3}\le\pi$ the (principal) argument tells us it is in the second quadrant (the top left), where $\arg(x+iy)=\pi-\arctan\frac{y}{-x}$ ("$-x$" because $x$ is negative and $-\arctan$ since we begin at $\pi$, on the negative real axis, and start turning clockwise - for this quadrant).

This means $k\lt 4$ but $5k+1\gt0$, so $-\frac{1}{5}\lt k\lt 4$. Let's compute the argument:

$$\begin{align}\arg(w+z)&\overset{\color{red}{1}}{=}\pi-\arctan\frac{5k+1}{4-k}=\frac{2\pi}{3}\\&\implies\frac{\pi}{3}=\arctan\frac{5k+1}{4-k}\\&\overset{\color{red}{2}}{\implies}\sqrt{3}=\frac{5k+1}{4-k}\\&\implies\sqrt{3}(4-k)=5k+1\\&\implies(5+\sqrt{3})k=4\sqrt{3}-1\\&\implies k=\frac{4\sqrt{3}-1}{5+\sqrt{3}}\end{align}$$

$1)$: It is also worth noting that we need $k\in\Bbb R$. If $k$ had an imaginary component, then $(k-4)$ would not be the real part and $(5k+1)$ would not be the imaginary part - they'd be a mix of both.

$2)$: It is worth noting that $\arctan(x)=y$ does not mean $x=\tan(y)$ in general. However, the way that the *principal argument* works, and by the fact we were careful with the quadrants, we know that it will hold for our purposes.

Comment: Thanks, this is clear now. I can't believe it says it right there in the question. THM: always draw all vectors before answering the questions!

Comment: @JosephZiminski This is certainly a good idea. It is a common mistake to muddle the arctangents when in different quadrants (and that, while multiplying and dividing complex numbers by adding/subtracting arguments is all very well, they usually want the principal argument from you so you need to take it modulo $2\pi$!)

Comment: +1: Nice detail, mentioning that you critically used the premise that $k \in \Bbb{R}.$

Answer (score 1):

> $w = k + i$ and $z = -4 + 5ki$
>
> Let $w + z = a + bi$.
>
> $a = k - 4 \\b =i + 5ki$

Typo: $b=1+5k.$

> The angle of the triangle formed by the complex number $w + z$ is $$\pi -\frac{2\pi}{3} = \frac{\pi}{3}.$$

"The triangle formed by $w + z$" is ambiguous.

In any case, your critical error is here, where you assume that $a$ and $b$ have the same sign:

> $$\tan\frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{b}{a}.$$

---

**Edit**

> The angle of the triangle formed by the vector w+z (on Argand diagram)

This is no less ambiguous than the original statement!

> I still do not understand however, although I made that bad assumption, how do you know the sign of $a$ and $b,$ to be able to answer the question?

Since the argument of $a+bi$ is $\dfrac23\pi,$ then $a$ is negative and $b$ positive.

So, $$\operatorname{Arg}(a+bi)=\pi-\arctan\left(\frac b{-a}\right).$$

In general, $$\tan(\arg z)=\frac{\Im (z)}{\Re (z)}\quad\text{if }\Re (z)\ne0,$$ and $$\cot(\arg z)=\frac{\Re (z)}{\Im (z)}\quad\text{if }\Im (z)\ne0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the improvements I have edited the question. I still do not understand however, although I made that bad assumption, how do you know the sign of a and b, to be able to answer the question? The angle of the vector w + z with the x-axis depends on the sign of a, b. But I do not see how to calculate a, b without first knowing the angle of the vector w + z and the x axis (which depends on a and b).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that one can simply say

$$
w+z=k+4+i(1+5k)\\
\arg(w+z)=\tan^{-1}\frac{1+5k}{k+4}=\frac{2\pi}{3}\\
\frac{1+5k}{k+4}=\tan\frac{2\pi}{3}=-\sqrt{3}\\
k=\frac{4\sqrt{3}-1}{5+\sqrt{3}}
$$